# Uncaught ReferenceError: GeolocationMarker is not defined

Tags: javascript, api, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers

I would like to set a marker in maps with a `GeolocationMarker`, but I only get the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GeolocationMarker is not defined

I use it like:

```
var geoMarker = new GeolocationMarker(mapAllDealer);

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(geoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
    mapAllDealer.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    mapAllDealer.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(geoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
    alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
});
```

Comment: Did you include [the GeolocationMarker library](https://chadkillingsworth.github.io/geolocation-marker/)?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, given that it's saying the principal symbol defined by the library isn't there, clearly what you need to look at is why the library isn't being successfully loaded -- load errors, etc.

Comment: But i thought that i don't have to include the files when they are in the plugins or bower directory. Or not ?

Comment: because i don't have any loading problems in the console

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue, and I removed the  **'use strict'** from the geolocation-marker.js file and it worked fine thereafter.